# How to find all ways to initiate a paste command in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, add-in, paste

I'm working on an add-in for MS Word and I'd like to create a custom handler for pasting (`EditPaste` is the built-in command). I can see that, by default, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Insert</kbd> are bound to `EditPaste`, and there are buttons which also initiate a paste.

Unfortunately, some keyboards have additional buttons/combinations which result in a paste action. Is there a way to detect these, possibly using VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not detectable, as far as I know, but here's a list:

1. **Paste** - from a Cut/Copy.

   - Paste text or an object: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>**
   - Paste special: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>ALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>**
   - Paste formatting only: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>**
   - Paste text or an object: **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>INSERT</kbd>**
2. **Paste** - from a Cut/Copy. (Note that **A**) these are for *Word 2007/2010 only* and **B)** they are keyboard sequences, not combinations.)

   - Keep Source Formatting: **<kbd>Alt</kbd>** and then **<kbd>H</kbd>**, **<kbd>V</kbd>**, **<kbd>K</kbd>**
   - Merge Formatting: **<kbd>Alt</kbd>** and then **<kbd>H</kbd>**, **<kbd>V</kbd>**, **<kbd>M</kbd>**
   - Keep Text Only: **<kbd>Alt</kbd>** and then **<kbd>H</kbd>**, **<kbd>V</kbd>**, **<kbd>T</kbd>**
3. **Paste** - from a Spike (Spike is *like* a secondary clipboard, it doesn't use Windows Clipboard. Cut to the Spike is **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>F3</kbd>**)

   - Paste from the Spike once: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>F3</kbd>**
   - Paste from the Spike multiple times: type the word *spike* and press **<kbd>F3</kbd>**
4. **Paste** - just once. (Select and cut using **<kbd>F2</kbd>** and then reposition the cursor anywhere)

   - Paste: **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

Comment: What is Spike? Is it a third-party tool, part of Windows, or included with Office?

Comment: @0xA3: It's part of Word. It's kind of a secondary clipboard. What it actually is is an AutoText entry that has a limited shelf life (it gets deleted as soon as you press F3). It's not really documented or taught anymore, especially now that AutoText is on it's way out due to Building Blocks and the like.